# How to access Properties set by "coder" inside say an overriding (named) Button Template in a xaml Dictionary

Tags: wpf, templates, resources

I am tearing my hair out trying to create a Style for the "Button bar" buttons in an App I am working on, but I want the developer to be able to specify the colors used in Button gradient fills etc by adding xaml code in their Button declaration for the BackGround, Foreground and BorderBrush colors.

I have used the "Copy Template" trick of a totally undefined  to get a copy of the full default Template for the control, but am totally confused by the way all the important colors are Hard coded internally in the style, being renamed with names such as "Button.Static.Background" which are all using HARD CODED COLORS attached to them eg:

> ```
> <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
> <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>''
> ```

and these are then referenced later on in the template by these names.  What I would really like to be able to do is to refer to the User defined properties for these items rather than hard coded values at this point in the template, but I cannot seem to find a way to do so.

As an example, here is what I am trying, but it doesn't work, although I do not get any errors as such.  The first line is a standard declaration, the next 2 are the ones I want to allow the user to override when using this style to match their preferred background/foreground color schemes.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="Black"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="{DynamicResource Background}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="{DynamicResource Border}"/>
```

Later on in the template we come to :-

```
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
   <Setter Property="Background" 
                        TargetName="border" 
                        Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" 
                        TargetName="border" 
                        Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
```

'''
and this is where I want the user defined colors (if supplied) to be used when the mouseover occurs, rather than any hard coded values ?
.
Am I trying to be too clever here, or is there a sensible way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a templated control based on nearly any control, this case being a button, and extend the control. You can add properties to allow users to specify the colors when using the control in the XAML. Of course, you’ll have to set default colors - likely being the colors you’ve used in your question.

Here’s an answer I wrote the other day on how to create a bindable control:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66394791/11590704

- The important part in the answer is the Dependency Properties and the `Template` property in the control’s `Style`. You **don’t** need to create a new control to use `TemplateBinding`.

You can use the same methods there and practically add any property you want. Foreground, MouseOverForeground, MouseOverBackground, etc.

An alternative would be to create a global theme. All your controls should use this theme (you’d likely have to create customized styles for each control to use the theme).

- You would declare the default theme colors in a resource dictionary like you did in your question.
- The benefit of a theme is that end users can customize the theme at run-time, e.g. change a button’s background color through the UI (you’d have to code in the theme adjustments in your .cs code). Also, your control will be visually coherent.
- This is a larger task though but I’d keep it in mind when creating your controls. I’ve had end users who need high contrasting colors so I created a theme and some code for theme adjustments.

---

#### EDIT - More Information

You don't have to create dependency properties for the base properties (although I suppose you can if you really wanted to). You can work around them in either the XAML or the callbacks/events in your control's code-behind.

Example: Working around the base background property.

```cs
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    //  Set the default background
    DefaultBackground = this.Background;
}

//  Store the default background color to revert back to
private Brush DefaultBackground;

//  Dependency property for mouse over background color
public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(MouseOverBackground), typeof(Brush),
    typeof(NavButton), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Transparent));

public Brush MouseOverBackground
{
    get => (Brush)GetValue(MouseOverBackgroundProperty);
    set => SetValue(MouseOverBackgroundProperty, value);
}

// On Mouse Enter => Set Background
protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);

    //  Set background color
    this.Background = MouseOverBackground;
}

// On Mouse Leave => Revert Background
protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);

    //  Set background color back
    this.Background = DefaultBackground;
}
```

I used the events already in the control to handle the background color states. This is a basic example using overrides for the event handlers but you can subscribe to the events directly.

And then your XAML will look like this:

```xml
<local:NavButton Background="Transparent" MouseOverBackground="Red"/>       

<!-- OR -->

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackground" Color="#1AFFFFFF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonMouseOverBackground" Color="#00897B" />

<local:NavButton Background="{DynamicResource ButtonBackground}" 
     MouseOverBackground="{DynamicResource ButtonMouseOverBackground}"/>
```

The triggers are handled in the code-behind.

---

#### EDIT 2: Some more information

I forgot to mention that triggers may not work unless you have default values set. You set the default values in the `Style`.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NavButton}">
    <!-- The default value -->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Grey" />
            
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <!-- The trigger value -->
            <Setter Property="Backround" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Many thanks for that detailed answer, it has been most helpful, BUT (there always is one ?) 

You mention :
"You can use the same methods there and practically add any property you want. Foreground, MouseOverForeground, MouseOverBackground, etc."  and I have indeed created a dependency property  for Background (SetBkGround) and for Content (SetText) . based on your suggestions.  Sadly, although I can debug the c

Comment: @IanTurner You likely wouldn't have to create dependency properties for base properties by the way, like `Background`, `Foreground`, `Visiblity`, `Content`, etc. because they're included in the base `Control` class your class should inherit. I'm not clear on what your question is, could you clarify a bit?

Comment: I  agree in principle, but in this (& others) cases I do need to "preset" some values rather than use the WPF defaults, but doing so as shown in my code results in the Triggers NOT changing them ?  Does that clarify my problem ?

Comment: @IanTurner I added more information to my answer. I hope it clarifies some things. You can customize your control to behave how you want to in the code-behind.

Comment: @IanTurner Sorry for the edits, I got something mixed up with some binding stuff in my prior edit and posted some wrong info but I fixed it

Comment: Wow, great follow up, thanks a lot, I think I now have a far better understanding of the problems (and ways to solve) the issues I had originally.  It is far more complex than I imagined, but nevertheless perfectly doable thanks to your invaluable and detailed answers.